# Why “rapporter des millions”?

Tags: sens, articles

In the following conversation (Jay Z to Beyoncé):

> Ton mariage te rapporte des millions.

Why is "rapporter *DES* millions" used and not "rapporter *LES* millions"?

Comment: Jay Z à Beyoncé : "Ton mariage te rapporte des millions"

Comment: I edited your question to add this. Note that the verb used is _rapporter_, not _rattraper_.

Comment: In this case it is just a difference between whether you should say "*some* millions" (then it is *des millions*) or "*the* millions" (there you say *les millions*).

Answer (score 9):

"*des*" is an undefined article whereas "*les*" is a defined article.

We don't know where do they (the millions) come from, so it is undefined.

"*les* millions" would imply that they are defined by a context (where do they come from).

For example:

- If they come from selling a house: "Ton mariage te rapporte *les* millions *de la maison*"
- If they come from winning the lottery: "Ton mariage te rapporte *les* millions *du loto*"

If we say just "*les* million" we consider that the person we're speaking to knows how they are defined, but it may be ambiguous. That's why the recommended way is to define them explicitly.

In the general case, money is not defined, that's why, you say most of the time "des millions".

Answer (score 3):

The amount does not refer to a specific set of millions, so we use the indefinite article. It could/will be ANY milions, not those/these specific ones (about which, we may have spoken earlier, for example).